# my_sizeof macro doesn't work for enumerated data type

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#define my_sizeof_one(type) (char *)(&type+1)-(char*)(&type)

int main(void)
{
   int answer;
   short x = 1;
   long y = 2;
   float u = 3.0;
   double v = 4.4;
   long double w = 5.54;
   char c = 'p';

   uint32_t e = 653;
   uint16_t f = 44;
   uint64_t g = 2323232;


   typedef enum
   {
      kCountInvalid,
      kCountOne,
      kCountTwo,
      kCountThree,
      kCountFour,
   }k_count_t;

  /* __DATE__, __TIME__, __FILE__, __LINE__ are predefined symbols */
  #if 1
  printf("Date : %s\n", __DATE__);
  printf("Time : %s\n", __TIME__);
  printf("File : %s\n", __FILE__);
  printf("Line : %d\n", __LINE__);
  #endif

  /* The size of various types */
  printf("The size of int             %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(answer));
  printf("The size of short           %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(x));
  printf("The size of long            %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(y));
  printf("The size of float           %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(u));
  printf("The size of double          %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(v));
  printf("The size of long double     %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(w));
  printf("The size of char            %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(c));
  printf("The size of enum            %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(k_count_t));

  printf("The size of uint16_t        %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(f));
  printf("The size of uint32_t        %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(e));
  printf("The size of uint64_t        %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(g));

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 error: expected expression before 'k_count_t'
 error: expected expression before 'k_count_t'
```

For some reason my_sizeof doesn't seem to work for enumerated data type in C.Can someone explain the reason for this?

Comment: Write out your macro and sub in k_count_t for type - the answer should become obvious.  You can't take the address of a type.  All of your other usages look like you pass variables.

Comment: but normal sizeof() build in macro in C does work for enumerated data type

Comment: the 'normal sizeof()' is not a macro, it's an operator understood by the compiler

Comment: There are two forms of `sizeof`. One takes an expression as an operand, the other takes a parenthesized type name. You can't write your own macro that handles both cases (unless it simply invokes `sizeof`, but then you'll have to use additional parentheses when invoking it).

Comment: @PeteBaughman - I was under the wrong impression that sizeof was a macro.Hence my amateurish attempt to write it on my own.

Comment: I ran your code (or parts of it).  I had no problem.  sizeof the enum type k_count_t is 4 bytes.  What type of compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: @ryker I don't think so. The code in the question won't compile anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a type to your macro, and the macro does not work for types. Because you cannot take the address of a type.

Although you've named the parameter of your macro `type`, that name is misleading. The macro accepts variables rather than types. Well, strictly it accepts anything for which you can take the address using the `&` operator. Notice that all your other uses of the macro are with variables. Supply a variable of type `k_count_t` to your macro and the compiler will be happy.

Of course, the real lesson to learn is to use `sizeof` like nature intended.

Comment: but normal sizeof() build in macro in C does work for enumerated data type

Comment: Please read the answer again. The issue has nothing at all to do with enums. The issue is the difference between a type and a variable. Note that `sizeof` is not a macro. One wonders why you don't use `sizeof`.

Comment: Perhaps an example would help.  printf("The size of int             %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(int)); has the same problem.  printf("The size of short           %zu\n", my_sizeof_one(short)); etc. . .

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I see things like `int *var = malloc(sizeof(int)*len);` Is this also not correct then?

Comment: @ryker That allocates an array of `int`, length `len`. That's fine. It uses `sizeof`. The question is about the macro defined in the code in the question. In other words, the question is not about `sizeof`.